# How can i get a session and avoid LazyInitialization Exception inside my Rest Layer?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

f got my application layer that works basically with spring+jsf(2.0) with primeFaces(3.5)+hibernate(4.3.5). Now we had to put a new way to access the DAO that goes outside the spring and the jsf, we have created a Rest path. The problem is: when i access my application with the browser and login first everything works correctly, including the Rest access to the DAO. The problem is when i try to access the Rest without the login. I tried to make a filter that intercept anything that goes through /rest/* path where i wrote:

```
@Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1, FilterChain arg2)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)arg0;
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
    HttpSession session2 = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    arg2.doFilter(arg0, arg1);
  }
```

But it doesn't work because the first session that i get is not the session that i want (it's outside the JSF context) and the first try to get the session from FacesContext gives me error because i'm outside JSF cycle that begins when i call something with *.jsf... the problem is that i can't call my Rest with a .jsp in the end and i can't get the data i need in DAO without the session. There is someway to bypass this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the @Transactional annotation. Thanks!